# array of unknown size as class member for making objects of array at runtime(object creating time)

Tags: c++, arrays, class, oop, compiler-errors

I want to construct a class of an array whose size is not known,
i want to make objects of array whose size would be initialized at the time when i would create an object(runtime)

```
class array_class{
public:
 int size_of_array;
 int arr[size_of_array];
 array_class(int p_size_of_array){ //constructor
     this->size_of_array=p_size_of_array;
 }
};
```

it say's error of invalid use of non static data member, what wrong am i doing(what should i have known)?.

Comment: Such dynamic array creation is illegal in some C++ standards, and the assignment does not reserve any memory at all.
Recommendation: use `std::vector` for such tasks.

Comment: @ThomasLang thank you for reply, which assignment doesn't reserve any memory at all, what should i have known about creating an array size at run time?

Comment: What you should have known is that you need to use `std::vector`. That's what it exists for: to create an array of a size that's determined at runtime. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how to use `std::vector`, and read it.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sir i know how to use an vector, what i want to create a vector my own i was stuck with iterator. i am trying to create my own vector container which contains an array of which size increases itself. i have seen these magic . i want to see behind the magic. i know i am not eligible for asking that so trying it in bits.

Comment: That's not how vectors work. They dynamically allocate a buffer for their values, and they also need to correctly implement things like constructing and destroying individual elements in the vector, which is actually a fairly advanced topic in of itself. Vectors do not contain arrays of size determined at runtime. That's not how they work.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa The implementation of `std::vector` uses a more or less infamous thing called `placement new`. This way, they can dynamically allocate needed memory in bytes and create objects at another point in time.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa If you want to know how `std::vector` works then just look in the `<vector>` header. all the code is there, although you may not find it easy to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to construct a class of an array whose size is not known
>
> (what should i have known)?

You should have known that is not not possible in C++. The size of all classes is compile time constant.

> i want to make objects of array whose size would be initialized at the time when i would create an object(runtime)

You need to allocate the array dynamically.

A simple solution:

```
struct array_class {
    std::vector<int> arr;
    array_class(int p_size_of_array) : arr(p_size_of_array) {}
};
```

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa It allocates the array dynamically.

Comment: The size of all classes is compile time constant, i still don't get this could you please explain this in my code context, where am i doing this voilation, thankyou

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa You are trying to create an array whose size is not known when the code is compiled (i.e. the size of the array is not a compile time constant). Because the size depends upon a variable it is only known when your code is run. This is not allowed in C++.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa Vectors use a technique called dynamic memory allocation, you could also use dynamic memory allocation directly in your class, but it's easier to use a vector because all the hard work has been done for you.

Comment: @ParsuramKailasa BTW If you really have all array sizes as compile time constants, you could provide a simple template class doing the same as `std::array` does.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have something like

```
void foo(int n)
{
    int vals[n];
}
```

in C++.

The thing is called [variable-length array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) and it's supported in C99.

By the way, it is the only thing I know which is supported in C99 and not supported in C++17 :).

`std::vector` is a nice alternative.

If you know the size of an array at the compile time, you may use `std::array`.

Answer (score 0):

@eerorika and @Nestor have good answers. To add to them here is a simple implementation of a vector i did some time ago you can take as a reference.

As you will see a basic way to have a variable length data structure, is to delete the underlying array and create a larger one if more or less memory is needed.

```
#pragma once

#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <stdexcept>

static constexpr size_t min_sz = 5;

template<typename T>
class Vector
{
public:
    class ConstIterator;
    class Iterator;
    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using const_reference = const value_type &;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    using const_pointer = const value_type *;
    using iterator = Vector::Iterator;
    using const_iterator = Vector::ConstIterator;

/// constructors, destructor, assign
    Vector()
    {
        allocEmpty(min_sz);
    }

    Vector(Vector<value_type> &vec)
    {
        allocEmpty(vec.max_sz);

        for (size_type i = 0; i < vec.sz; ++i)
            values[i] = vec.values[i];

        sz = vec.sz;
    }

    Vector(size_type size)
    {
        allocEmpty(size);
    }

    Vector(const std::initializer_list<value_type> &list)
    {
        allocEmpty(list.size());

        size_type i = 0;
        for (const auto &val : list)
        {
            values[i] = val;
            ++i;
        }
        sz = list.size();
    }

    ~Vector()
    {
        delete[] values;
    }

    Vector &operator=(const Vector &other)
    {
        reserve(other.sz);

        for (size_type i = 0; i < other.sz; ++i)
            values[i] = other.values[i];

        sz = other.sz;

        return *this;
    }

/// element access
    reference operator[](size_type position)
    {
        if (position >= sz)
            throw std::out_of_range ("operator[] out of range: sz = " + std::to_string(sz) + " but position = " + std::to_string(position));

        return values[position];
    }

    const_reference operator[](size_type position) const
    {
        if (position >= sz)
            throw std::out_of_range ("operator[] out of range: sz = " + std::to_string(sz) + " but position = " + std::to_string(position));

        return values[position];
    }

    const_reference front() const
    {
        if (sz == 0)
            throw std::out_of_range ("front called on empty container");
        return values[0];
    }

    const_reference back() const
    {
        if (sz == 0)
            throw std::out_of_range ("back called on empty container");
        return values[sz - 1];
    }

    pointer data()
    {
        if (sz > 0)
            return values;

        return nullptr;
    }

    const_pointer data() const
    {
        if (sz > 0)
            return values;

        return nullptr;
    }

/// capacity
    size_type size() const
    {
        return sz;
    }

    size_type capacity() const
    {
        return max_sz;
    }

    bool empty() const
    {
        return (sz == 0);
    }

    void reserve(size_type size)
    {
        if (size <= min_sz)
            return;

        value_type *newArray = new value_type[size];

        for (size_type i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
            newArray[i] = values[i];

        delete[] values;

        values = newArray;
        max_sz = size;
    }

    void shrink_to_fit()
    {
        size_type newSize = (sz >= min_sz) ? sz : min_sz;
        value_type *newArray = new value_type[newSize];

        for (size_type i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
            newArray[i] = values[i];

        delete[] values;

        values = newArray;
        max_sz = newSize;
    }

/// modifiers
    void push_back(const value_type &value)
    {
        if (sz >= max_sz)
            reserve(max_sz * 2);

        values[sz] = value;
        ++sz;
    }

    void resize(size_type count)
    {
        reserve(count);
        sz = count;
    }

    void resize(size_type count, const value_type &value)
    {
        reserve(count);
        for (size_type i = sz; i < count; ++i)
            values[i] = value;

        sz = count;
    }

    void insert(size_type position, const value_type &value)
    {
        if (position > sz)
            throw std::out_of_range ("insert out of range: sz = " + std::to_string(sz) + " but position = " + std::to_string(position));

        if (sz >= max_sz)
            reserve(max_sz * 2);

        for (size_type i = sz; i > position; --i)
            values[i] = values[i - 1];

        values[position] = value;
        ++sz;
    }

    iterator insert(const_iterator pos, const_reference val) 
    {
        auto diff = pos - begin();
        if (diff < 0 || static_cast<size_type>(diff) > sz)
            throw std::runtime_error("Iterator out of bounds");

        size_type current = static_cast<size_type>(diff);
        if (sz >= max_sz)
            reserve(max_sz * 2);

        for (size_t i = sz; i-->current;)
            values[i + 1] = values[i];

        values[current] = val;
        ++sz;
        return iterator(values + current);
    }

    void erase(size_type position)
    {
        if (position >= sz)
            throw std::out_of_range ("erase out of range: sz = " + std::to_string(sz) + " but position = " + std::to_string(position));

        for (size_type i = position; i < sz - 1; ++i)
            values[i] = values[i + 1];

        --sz;
    }

    iterator erase(const_iterator pos) 
    {
        auto diff = pos - begin();
        if (diff < 0 || static_cast<size_type>(diff) >= sz)
            throw std::runtime_error("Iterator out of bounds");

        size_type current = static_cast<size_type>(diff);
        for (size_type i = current; i < sz - 1; ++i)
            values[i] = values[i + 1];

        --sz;
        return iterator(values + current);
    }

    void pop_back()
    {
        if (sz == 0)
            throw std::out_of_range ("pop_back on empty container");

        if (sz > 0) --sz;
    }

    void clear()
    {
        sz = 0;
    }

/// iterators
    iterator begin()
    {
        if (sz == 0)
            return end();

        return iterator(values);
    }

    iterator end()
    {
        return iterator(values + sz);
    }

    const_iterator begin() const
    {
        if (sz == 0)
            return end();

        return ConstIterator(values);
    }

    const_iterator end() const
    {
        return ConstIterator(values + sz);
    }

/// private section
private:
    void allocEmpty(size_type size)
    {
        auto newSize = (size > min_sz) ? size : min_sz;
        sz = 0;
        values = new value_type[newSize];
        max_sz = newSize;
    }

private:
    value_type *values;

    size_type sz;
    size_type max_sz;

/// iterator implementations
public:
    class Iterator
    {
    public:
        using value_type = Vector::value_type;
        using reference = Vector::reference;
        using pointer = Vector::pointer;
        using difference_type = Vector::difference_type;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    public:
        Iterator()
        {
            ptr = nullptr;
        }

        Iterator(pointer ptr)
        {
            this->ptr = ptr;
        }

        reference operator*() const
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        pointer operator->() const
        {
            return ptr;
        }

        iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        iterator operator++(int)
        {
            iterator it = *this;
            ++ptr;
            return it;
        }

        iterator operator+ (difference_type difference) const
        {
            return iterator(ptr + difference);
        }

        bool operator==(const const_iterator &it) const
        {
            return it == ptr;
        }

        bool operator!=(const const_iterator &it) const
        {
            return it != ptr;
        }

        operator const_iterator() const
        {
            return const_iterator(ptr);
        }

    private:
        pointer ptr;
    };

    class ConstIterator
    {
    public:
        using value_type = Vector::value_type;
        using reference = Vector::const_reference;
        using pointer = Vector::const_pointer;
        using difference_type = Vector::difference_type;
        using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    public:
        ConstIterator()
        {
            ptr = nullptr;
        }

        ConstIterator(pointer ptr)
        {
            this->ptr = ptr;
        }

        reference operator*() const
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        pointer operator->() const
        {
            return ptr;
        }

        const_iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++ptr;
            return *this;
        }

        const_iterator operator++(int)
        {
            const_iterator it = *this;
            ++ptr;
            return it;
        }

        bool operator==(const const_iterator &it) const
        {
            return it.ptr == ptr;
        }

        bool operator!=(const const_iterator &it) const
        {
            return it.ptr != ptr;
        }

        Vector::difference_type operator-(const const_iterator &rop)
        {
            return ptr - rop.ptr;
        }

    private:
        pointer ptr;
    };

};

/// non-member functions
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const Vector<T> &lop, const Vector<T> &rop)
{
    if (lop.size() != rop.size()) return false;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < lop.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (lop[i] != rop[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Vector<T> &vec)
{
    out << '[';
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i)
    {
        if (i > 0) out << ", ";
        out << vec[i];
    }
    out << ']';
    return out;
}
```